# Conditional JSON parse and append

Tags: python, json, if-statement, parsing

On the multidimensional JSON below i had extracted the "width" and "height" values as i want to append on an empty table/array and use them later for calculations. On the following JSON.

```html
[
{
 "frame_id":1, 
 "filename":"bake/IMG_20210930_090024.jpg", 
 "objects": [ 
  {"class_id":0, "name":"brick", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x":1279, "top_y": 991, "width": 922, "height":1164},"relevant":true}
 ] 
}, 
{
 "frame_id":2, 
 "filename":"bake/IMG_20210930_090017.jpg", 
 "objects": [ 
  {"class_id":1, "name":"limestone", "relative_coordinates":{"left_x":1672, "top_y":1536, "width": 651, "height": 623},"relevant":true}
 ] 
}
]
```

My code and result:

```
with open('/home/pan/output/result.json') as json_data:
data = json.load(json_data)
for item in data:
for row in item.get('objects', []):
print(row['class_id'], row['relative_coordinates']['width'],row['relative_coordinates']['height'])

0 922 1164
1 651 623
```

My main question would be that i would like to show the results only for "class_id":0 for width and height.
Also whats the best way to append those values through the console or an empty array[] and make calculations later?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
value_list = []
with open('result.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for item in data:
        for row in item.get('objects', []):
            if row['class_id'] == 0:
                print(row['class_id'], row['relative_coordinates']['width'], row['relative_coordinates']['height'])
                value_list.append(row['relative_coordinates']['width'])
                value_list.append(row['relative_coordinates']['height'])

print(value_list)
```

**Output:**

```
0 922 1164
[922, 1164]
```

Comment: It's better to have the loop `for item in data` separate so that we dont have to keep the file open after we have got the data from it.

Comment: I just try to keep code same as it is that's why write like this else we can read the file using a variable and do rest of things with that variable. :)

Answer (score 0):

You get to your data by slogging through the dicts and lists one by one.

```
width = -1
height = -1
for item in data:
    if item['objects'][0]['class_id'] == 0:
        width = item['objects'][0]['relative_coordinates']['width']
        height ​= item['objects'][0]['relative_coordinates']['height']
        break
```

Comment: That's simply not true.  I check all of the items in the outer list.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `if` condition in your code will give the expected results as below:

```
data = None
with open('/home/pan/output/result.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
co_ordinates = []
for item in data:
    for row in item.get('objects', []):
        if row['class_id'] == 0:
            co_ordinates.append(row['relative_coordinates']['width'])
            co_ordinates.append(row['relative_coordinates']['height'])
            break
            
print (co_ordinates)
```

Output:

```
[922, 1164]
```